# Testing Spring-Integration with subscriber channel

Tags: testing, groovy, spring-integration, publish-subscribe, channel

I have the following:

Direct-Channel => Splitter => PublishSubscribeChannel

I would like to send data to the direct-channel and test the outcome in the publish-subscribe-channel

What I have so far partly taken from [Spring.io](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/integration/107842-develop-junit-test-cases-for-spring-intergration-application) (and it works only if I step through debug mode) is:

```
DirectChannel incomeChannel
PublishSubscribeChannel subscribeChannel

@Test
public void test() {
    final AtomicInteger count  = new AtomicInteger()

    assert true == subscribeChannel.subscribe(new MessageHandler() {
        void handleMessage(Message<?> message) throws MessagingException {
            count.getAndIncrement();
            Entity response = message.getPayload()
            assert response != null
            // assertions ...
        }
    })

    def request = MessageBuilder.withPayload(entities).build()
    assert incomeChannel.send(request) == true

    Thread.sleep(10000)
    assert 0 < count.get()
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't show your configuration but, if your pub sub channel has a task executor, you need to add a latch; you also should do the asserts on the main thread...

```
@Test
public void test() {
    final AtomicReference<Message<?>> messageRef = new AtomicReference<>();
    final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);

    assert true == subscriberChannel.subscribe(new MessageHandler() {
        void handleMessage(Message<?> message) throws MessagingException {
            messageRef.set(message);
            latch.countDown();
        }
    })

    def request = MessageBuilder.withPayload(entities).build()
    assert incomeChannel.send(request) == true
    assert true == latch.await(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    Entity response = msg.get().getPayload()
    assert response != null
    // assertions ...

}
```

Comment: Forgot to add `latch.await()` assertion.

Comment: Hi Gary, thank you very much for your reply, it helps a lot already. But somehow I am missing the concept somehow. The sending of message (stubmessage) to the incomeChannel it takes long time that the splitter will be called. You mentioned the task executor, I have to do something with that? I fit my code in the questions and added configuration ... Thank you in advance

Comment: You should be sure that your `subscribeChannel` is exactly that `subscribe.channel` bean

Comment: I meant that __IF__ you have a task executor on the channel, then your main test thread must wait somehow until the task completes - hence the latch. If you __DON'T__ have an executor then I have no idea why your test fails. Please edit the question to show your COMPLETE configuration.

Comment: you are right, the test works. In the configuration I added the part what keeps the test away to pass. In fact this is the complete relevant xml code of the config file.

Comment: I guess I need to split my xmls in case I want to test them separately and do one xml what includes them. And somehow I swapped the request-channel and reply-channel in the http:outbound

Comment: Okey Gary, I fixed it. But as it is a new topic and doesnt fit to your answer, I will bring back the original questions, so it fits to your answer and may be helpful for others... Thank you very much for your patience.